# Predict() won't give standard errors for mixed-effects logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, predict, lme4

I would like to calculate the predicted probability for a logistic regression. The dependent variable is a dummy variable. The `predict()` function is not allowing me to get the standard errors, which I need to calculate the confidence interval for the predicted value.

```
library(lme4) 

# Create function
cham <- glmer(mentionedpresorpreslastname ~ poly(presvoteshare,3)+ 
        preselyear + all_approvalS + 
        samepartyapprovals + samepartyaspotus +  
        membervoteshareS +
        republican + minorityparty  +
        congservedattimeofpr + leadership + 
        bachdegree + (1|memberidnum), 
        data=bothpres, model=binomial("logit"))

#Create new data for prediction
pp1 <- with(bothpres, data.frame(samepartyaspotus = 1,
       presvoteshare = mean(presvoteshare), preselyear = 0, 
       all_approvalS = mean(all_approvalS), 
       samepartyapprovals=mean(samepartyapprovals),
       membervoteshareS = mean(membervoteshareS), republican = 0,
       minorityparty = 0,                  
       congservedattimeofpr=mean(congservedattimeofpr),
       leadership = 0, bachdegree=mean(bachdegree)))

predictions1 <- as.data.frame(predict(cham, pp1, se.fit="TRUE", 
type="link", re.form=~0))
```

Predictions1 returns a single value and

> Warning message:
>   In predict.merMod(cham, pp1, se.fit = "TRUE", type = "link", re.form = ~0) : unused arguments ignored

Comment: there is no `se.fit` argument. [this post](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/147) was a while ago but maybe it still holds, but the [faq](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#predictions-andor-confidence-or-prediction-intervals-on-predictions) offers one approach

Comment: @user20650 is correct. The warning message is very specific. Also, specifying boolean/logical values is never quoted.